# SQL JOIN WITH DISTINCT

Tags: sql, join

I am trying to do a query to join to tables as below I am wanting to Join the HighestQual and QualSubject from TABLE 2 to all the columns from TABLE 1 Where Table 1 Status = 'FINAL' but by doing a JOIN based on the EmpID I am getting duplicate rows because there are 2 rows in TABLE 2 with the same EmpID.

How can I get this to return this with only one row? Any help would be great - I have tried all joins (I think) and Distinct, but am unsure of how to do it with out duplicating the row for the particular Application (AppID) as a user could have 2 Applications (AppIDs) in at the same time so need to show both of these.

```
    TABLE 1                               TABLE 2  
----------------------               ------------------
EmpID |AppID |AppName |Status        EmpID | HighestQual | QualSubject
----- |----- |--------|------        ----- |------------ |-------------
001   | 001  | A NAME | FINAL        001   | Bsc         | A Subject
001   | 002  | A NAME | FINAL        002   | BA          | B Subject
002   | 003  | B NAME | FINAL        001   | MSc         | C Subject
```

What I am trying to achieve is

```
EmpID | AppID | AppName | Status | HighestQual | QualSubject
------------------------------------------------------------
001   | 001   | A NAME  | FINAL  | MSc         | C Subject
001   | 002   | A NAME  | FINAL  | MSc         | C Subject
002   | 003   | B NAME  | FINAL  | BA          | B Subject
```

But i keep getting a duiplicate of the AppID because the join includes both rows from table 2.

Any help or point in the right direction will be great.

Thanks

Comment: you should include a condition from QualSubject to get what you need

Comment: Based on your model, two rows from table 2 for EmpID 001 is correct, if you do not place a condition on table 2. Is "HighestQual" Ranked in some way (PhD, MSc, Bsc, BA)? if so, you could join oin a query on table 2 where you only return each row with the highest rank....

Comment: What rules is to select MSc instead of Bsc?

Comment: *EmpID 001* is mapped to both *BSc* and *MSc* in table2. By what logic should *MSc* be chosen before *BSc*? SQL can't make the choice for you, so you'll have to be explicit on what data you want to join and how it should be mapped.

Comment: The highest qual is free text but you can add another qualification which doesnt have to be the highestqual you could add on a training course as a qualsubject and then add the BSc or what ever as the highest still. The system is already implemented so I cannot reverse engineer anything I just need to work with what it is unfortunately.

Comment: There is a date field in TABLE 2 so I could do it on the latest date but how can I just get it to return the latest date in an inner Join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your desired output, based on the example data you gave, the following could be used (MySql and SQL-server):

```
SELECT t1.EmpID, t1.AppID, t1.AppName, t1.Status, MAX(t2.HighestQual), MAX(t2.QualSubject)
FROM Table1 t1 
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.EmpID = t2.EmpID 
WHERE t1.Status = 'FINAL'
GROUP BY t1.EmpID, t1.AppID, t1.AppName, t1.Status
```

But this is not true *ranking* since it only uses `MAX()` for *Highestqual* and *QualSubject*. This means that *MSc* will be chosen before *Bsc*, and *C subject* will be chosen before *A subject*.

This can be improved and expanded with either a better ranking field, or sub selects, or some `case statements`, or a `partition`, etc.

If you're using SQL-server (2008 or above), the below example will also produce the same results using `NTILE()`:

```
SELECT t1.EmpID, t1.AppID, t1.AppName, t1.Status, t2.HighestQual, t2.QualSubject
FROM Table1 t1  
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT EmpID, HighestQual, QualSubject, 
  NTILE(2) over(partition by EmpID order by HighestQual desc) As Rank
  FROM Table2
) t2 ON t2.EmpID = t1.EmpID
WHERE t1.Status = 'FINAL' AND t2.Rank = 1
```

This could probably be condensed to not use the sub select, but right now I can't think of how. There are many other options available, as per usual when it comes to SQL.

Comment: Hi Thanks for this - the first one got me the closest - it seemed to bring back both fields from TABLE 2 but when I tested the query it only returned 56 records but if I do a SELECT * WHERE Status = ' FINAL' I get 98? So I am a bit confused by this, could some of the groupings over complicate this? Or do you know where this could have gone slightly off?

Comment: @KlydeMonroe The "issue" is most likely with the `inner join`. This will only return records that exist in both tables. Try changing that to a `left join`, just to test if the data makes more sense. This will return all records from table1, and those matching from table2.

Comment: Thank you very much you were correct about the join - it seems that not all users had a row in TABLE 2 there for they were not being returned. Thanks Again